# tuleap redirects to old ip address even though dhcp server has assigned new ip to machine

Tags: tuleap

Dhcp server has assigned a new ip to my tuleap machine but my tuleap url redirects to an old ip on my login.php link and hence I am not able to use tuleap. Can anyone suggest some resolution.?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for urls in the local.inc file you'll find at `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc`.

You must replace all incorrect urls here.

Comment: @av1031: If it does then be sure to [accept](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.